# Repeats the custom attribute

Tags: magento2, checkout, attributes, custom, custom-attributes

when I use this method to get custom attributes

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($block->getItem()->getProductId());
echo '<span>' . $_product->getData('custom_attribute'). '</span>';
```

in this place design/fronend/theme/Magento_Checkou/templates/cart/item/default.phtml (page checkout/cart, list products), this method repeat custom attribute. When a product has no attribute, it takes from the previous product.

Comment: you what you want to i don't understand???

Comment: I don't want to print this attribute (custom_attribute) for a product, that doesn't have it.

Comment: you are add if condition and check attribute or not

Comment: for ex:- $value = $product->getData('custom_attribute'));
if ($value) {
    //print value here
}
else
{
}

Comment: Yes, I checked with if condition and it still doesn't work. I also checked the product id number and it is correct.

Comment: solve the issues ???

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. I just wrote that, i checked the product id, the number (id product) is correct and it gets a bad value.

Comment: it should be better if `you could show what You wrote.

Comment: Sure, https://imgur.com/a/LbtjFhf 
I also used with isset, it still works so that if it has no value (short_description, quantity) it takes from the previous product.